# Infinite scrolling and json endpoint

Tags: htmx

I have an endpoint that populates JSON objects. The endpoint is paginated:

```
example.com/articles?page=1
```

Incrementing the page number goes to the next page.
My htmx code block looks like this (I am using nunjucks for templating).

```
  <div hx-ext="client-side-templates">
    <div hx-get="http://localhost:8080/dev.bigcyprus.com.cy/web/api/v1/articles?page=0"
     hx-trigger="revealed" hx-swap="afterend" nunjucks-template="m_template">
    <template id="m_template">
      {% for row in rows %}
        <li>{{ row.title }}</l1>
      {% endfor %}
    </template>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The above code block will generate the first page of the results but that's it. I am reading through the [docs example](https://htmx.org/examples/infinite-scroll/) but cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing too keep in mind is that `revealed` event is triggered only once - when the element was revealed for the first time.

With that, let's take a look at the example from the docs

> Let’s focus on the final row (or the last element of your content):
>
> [code sample]
>
> This **last element contains a listener** which, when scrolled into view, will trigger a request.

The infinite scrolling example appends a new `hx-get` element after each load at the very end of the feed and triggers next request once the user reaches the end. To achieve this behavior with JSON API, you need to make sure that your client side templates includes similar element, for example

```html
<template id="m_template">
  {% for row in rows %}
    <li>{{ row.title }}</l1>
  {% endfor %}
  <li hx-get="{{next_page}}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="revealed" nunjucks-template="m_template"></li>
</template>
```

Example above assumes you have `next_page` field in your response, so you may need to adjust to your scenario

Comment: Appreciate the help...indeed "last element contains a listener" is a key statement. Works fine when adapted using your answer.